# Actionscript 3 code one frame delay

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, frame, delay, puppet

I'm creating a puppet rig for an animation I am making. I've created two custom classes that inherit from the MovieClip class. One is the head I'm animating facing the camera and another is the 3/4ths view of the same head. I've modified both constructors to add an event listener that calls the function `facRig` which helps me animate the heads by calling other functions like `moveEyes(), moveMouth()` etc.

```
public function _F__MichaelFULLHEAD() {
    super();
    faceRig("OverLoad"); //<--bug workaround
    this.gotoAndPlay(MovieClip(root).currentFrame); //Sync movieclips with timeline
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,faceRig);
}
```

However, the function is always called one frame after the `MovieClip` appears in the timeline. This delay makes animating impossible because I have to constantly switch between the front view and the 3/4ths view (I switch by making a new keyframe in the timeline and dragging the symbol from the library). Every time I switch there is one frame where the mouth is not talking and the eyes are not moving.

The "bug workaround" kinda solves the problem. Now first time either head appears on stage it begins animating immediately, but if I switch from the front view to the 3/4ths view back to the front view, the front view gets delayed again.

I suspected this might be because the constructor doesn't get run again so i tried to make each instance of the heads unique by naming them `frontHead1` and `frontHead2` in the object's property box, however it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to my own problem:

```
public function _F__MichaelFULLHEAD() {
    super();
    //this.gotoAndPlay(MovieClip(root).currentFrame); << Moved this to inside faceRig
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,faceRig);
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED,faceRig);
}
```

Apparently `Event.ADDED` runs before `Event.ENTER_FRAME` which contradicts what I thought I knew about how `Event.ENTER_FRAME` worked. Now everything works as it should.